# Plotting multiple columns against one column in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

In my `data` I have 12 columns called `X1` to `X12` plus one additional column called `x`. Using `ggplot2` package, I was wondering how to plot each of the columns `X1` to `X12` as the y-axis, against the same `x` column as the x-axis?

I suspect I need a `facet_wrap()` for each of `X1` to `X12` as the y-axis, and `x` as the x-axis. So we will have 12 plots each with one of `X1` to `X12` as the y-axis, and the same `x` column as the x-axis.

**Note:** I need a `geom_line`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/vp_cond.csv')

long <- pivot_longer(data, everything()) # do we need to do this before plotting?
```

Comment: What kind of graph you are looking for `ggplot(long, aes(x = name, y = value)) + geom_boxplot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `pivot_longer` (or `gather`) and facets to achieve this.

One issue is that by default the labels will not be in the order X1 - X12, so you will need to specify the factor levels.

Try this:

```
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:12) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = paste0("X", 1:12))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~name) +
  theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `geom_line` with `facet_wrap`

```
library(ggplot2)
data %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -x) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x, value)) + 
        geom_line() + 
        facet_wrap(~ name)
```

Comment: @rnorouzian you replied earlier to my comment that it is `geom_point`

Comment: Thank you so much, I highly appreciate it, I have a couple of follow-ups about the data itself in a bit.